# How to handle this merge conflict case when using EDIFF where we will need some portion of conflicts from both Varients A and B

Tags: emacs, git-merge-conflict, emacs-ediff

In some cases we would need some portion of code from both varients line in Image below. How can we handle this case using `EDIFF` so that the final result will be

```js
import { apple, banana, coconut } from 'fruits'
```

[image]

Comment: Got it, I can make an edit on Variant C, didn't know that

Comment: Be sure to *answer* your own question.  You can then *accept* your answer.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656311/conflict-resolution-with-emacs-ediff-how-can-i-take-the-changes-of-both-version